# How to pass parameters in emberjs render method?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, modal-dialog

I am trying to pass parameters to a modal view while rendering it. Here is what I got so far:

In my application route, I have:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    openModal: function(modal, opts) {

      return this.render(modal, {
        into: 'application',
        outlet: 'modal'
        model: function(){ return opts },
        controller: modal
      });
    },
    closeModal: function() {
      return this.disconnectOutlet({
        outlet: 'modal',
        parentView: 'application'
      });
    }
  }
});
```

I have a general modal view:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'div',
  classNames: 'modal'.w(),
  didInsertElement: function() {
    console.log("did insert element");
    this.$().attr('id', 'modal');
    this.$().modal({
      keyboard: false,
      backdrop: 'static'
    });

    return this.$().modal('show');
  },
  willDestroyElement: function() {
    return this.$().modal('hide');
  }
});
```

and a view specific to my modal:

```
import ModalView from '../modal';
export default ModalView.extend();
```

I want 'opts' (passed as an argument in openModal) to be processed so that I can fill the content of the modal depending on it. So far I cannot get anything from my modal controller:

```
import ModalController from '../modal'

export default ModalController.extend({
  init: function(){
    console.log('initializing modal');
    console.log(this.get('model'));
    console.log(this);
  },
  actions: {
    confirm: function() {
      //alert('OK, it will be done!');
      return this.send('closeModal');
    }
  }
});
```

What would be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out, there has to be a better to do it but the following should work for me:

Application route:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    openModal: function(modal, opts) {
      this.controllerFor(modal).set('model', opts);
      return this.render(modal, {
        into: 'application',
        outlet: 'modal'
      });
    },
    closeModal: function() {
      return this.disconnectOutlet({
        outlet: 'modal',
        parentView: 'application'
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Controller of my modal window:

```
import ModalController from '../modal'

export default ModalController.extend({
  modalContent: "test",
  actions: {
    confirm: function() {
      //alert('OK, it will be done!');
      return this.send('closeModal');
    }
  },
  idUpdated: function(){
    var id = this.get('model').id;
    console.log(id);
    // Update modal content with the id here
    // Ajax request goes here.

  }.observes("id")
});
```

Comment: I think that you should not need explicit call `this.controllerFor(modal).set('model', opts);`, did you tried `.observes('id').on('init')`?

Comment: You're right, I can just pass opts in the `model:` option of render. I got `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null` when adding `.on('init')` after `observes('id')`. Not sure why you suggested it :).

Answer (score 0):

try to change to:

```
openModal: function(modal, opts) {

  return this.render(modal, {
    into: 'application',
    outlet: 'modal'
    model: opts, // here
    controller: modal
  });
}
```

Comment: I just tried it, actually I see my model in `console.log(this)` but I dont know how to access it.

Comment: I just did some reading, it looks like I cannot access the model on init, not sure what to do now...

Comment: Yes, because router will fill it after initialization. May you describe why you need it at init? Why do not access it from template or inside view's didInsertElement, if you need to execute some logic before modal opened.

Comment: for example call `console.log(this.get('controller.model'));` inside didInsertElement

Comment: I posted my own answer, feel free to improve it if you want :).